# startxfce4 black screen

Tags: xfce

Im new to Ubuntu. Regardless, I am on a HP Chromebook 11 G4. After installing crouton, my chroot is erroring out. startxfce4 blacks out my screen. After some time it switches back to Chrome OS.

> xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
>
> setversion 1.4 failed: Permission denied
>
> crouton: version 1-20161129162558~master:5f2f11f9
>
> release: precise
>
> architecture: amd64
>
> xmethod: xorg
>
> targets: xfce
>
> host: version 9249.0.0 (Official Build) canary-channel kip
>
> kernel: Linux localhost 4.4.44-07075-g4f05945 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 3
>   19:24:34 PST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> freon: yes
>
> /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: 1: /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: ssh-agent: not found
>
> _IceTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.ICE-unix should be set to root
>
> xfdesktop[21294]: starting up
>
> (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:21298): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion `string != NULL' failed
>
> (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:21298): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
>
> (xfce4-settings-helper:21313): xfce4-settings-helper-WARNING **: Failed to get the _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS property.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xfdesktop` in the terminal without root

Answer (score -1):

xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)

Xorg is trying IO as non-root or even root on ubuntu 22.04 ...

try this as root:

sudo setcap CAP_SYS_RAWIO+eip /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg

Then restart Xorg

I hope it helps

Comment: Can you explain what you are suggesting to do with this commands?

Comment: above command allow IOPL by Xorg, permitting I/O operation; for more info: man capabilities